# Differences between requirements for a software architect and highly experienced developer?

Tags: recruitment, software-development

When the company post a job announcement for a "software architect" role, what additional specific requirements this implies, in comparison to the "senior developer" or "highly experienced developer" role?

If I have never been actually an "architect" but have lots of truly deep experience with all technologies listed (as a programmer), would I qualify or do they need something additional?

Comment: Job titles come and go. just a mechanism to make people think they are more important and also for the company for avoid a pay rise

Comment: Have you designed a complete application or a software system that was a success? Are you aware of the pitfalls that wreck system development?

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39284/whats-the-difference-between-a-software-architect-a-software-engineer-and-a-so

Answer (score 2):

Software architect is not just developing, it's also about designing, setting technical standards, coding protocols, platforms and everything else.

I would think that a solid developer would be able to handle the job. But it's definitely not the same.